# Is there a better way to parse value into multiple columns?

Tags: t-sql

I have a value that needs to be parsed into a potential three values:

| MasterUnit | Unit1 | Unit2 | Unit3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10ABC | 10A | 10B | 10C |
| 10AB | 10A | 10B | NULL |

I'm accomplishing what I need in the below script. My question to you... Is there a better, more efficient  way to do so (in fewer lines of code)?

```
cast([UnitNum] as char(5)) as MasterUnit,
left(cast([UnitNum] as char(5)), 3) as Unit1,
case
when (left(left(cast([UnitNum] as char(5)), 2) + right(cast([UnitNum] as char(5)), 2),3)) = left(cast([UnitNum] as char(5)), 2)
then NULL
else (left(left(cast([UnitNum] as char(5)), 2) + right(cast([UnitNum] as char(5)), 2),3))
end as Unit2,
case
when (left(cast([UnitNum] as char(5)), 2)) + (right(cast([UnitNum] as char(5)), 1)) = left([UnitNum],2)
then NULL
else (left(cast([UnitNum] as char(5)), 2) + right(cast([UnitNum] as char(5)), 1))
end as Unit3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a little bit of string manipulation and a `CROSS APPLY`

```
Select A.* 
      ,Unit1 = S1+nullif(substring(S2,1,1),'')
      ,Unit2 = S1+nullif(substring(S2,2,1),'')
      ,Unit3 = S1+nullif(substring(S2,3,1),'')
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( values ( left(MasterUnit,patindex('%[^0-9]%',MasterUnit)-1),substring(MasterUnit,patindex('%[^0-9]%',MasterUnit),100) ) ) B(S1,S2)
```

**Reults**

[image]

Comment: Makes perfect sense! I hadn't thought about a cross apply. Exactly what I needed and in less code! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Making some assumptions about your sample data, perhaps something like the following using a *cross apply* to re-use the initial two characters is about as minimal as possible :

```
select MasterUnit,
    u + NullIf(Substring(MasterUnit,3,1),'') Unit1,
    u + NullIf(substring(MasterUnit,4,1),'') Unit2,
    u + NullIf(substring(MasterUnit,5,1),'') Unit3
from t
cross apply(values(Left(MasterUnit,2)))m(u);
```

Comment: Another great suggestion (with the cross apply and reusing the first two characters). Much appreciated, Stu!